# How do i fix error connection timed out while connecting to remote mysql using node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I've been trying to make a connection to mysql db remotley using node js.Everything worked fine before my hosting providers made migration to newer cpanel version(because of installing SSL certificate),but since then i always get err connection timed out.

I double-checked connection params(hostname,username,db etc.)and they are correct also i added my ip address(my pc i'm connecting from) to whitelist in cpanel.I even tried to connect using mysql workbench but it doesn't work either.
Here's my connection string:

```
import mysql from "mysql2"

   const pool = mysql.createPool({
   host: '******',
   user: '*********',
   password: '*****',
   database: '******',
   connectionLimit:100,
   port:3306
  
  
   }).promise()

    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
     if (connection) {
     console.log("Connected")
     }
```

I think that for some reason my root user lost all permissions during this migration,beacause when i try to add privileges to another user in phpmyadmin i get 'Access denied for user root@localhost', or maybe the port 3306 is blocked but i have no idea how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

If your database host is different between nodejs and mysql table head, it will
timeout.

Example: nodejs connect pool host is `127.0.0.1`,

```js
pool = mysql.createPool({  
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "user",
  password: "",
  database: "nodejs",
  port: 3306,
});
```

mysql host is `localhost`

```
Source Server         : localhost
Source Server Version : 50624
Source Host           : localhost:3306
Source Database       : nodejs

Target Server Type    : MYSQL
Target Server Version : 50624
File Encoding         : 65001
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I’ve also checked that but now i see thet even when i try to run telnet <hostname> 3306,i get connection timeout so i think the port is blocked or something.I will try contacting my hostig providers…